# How to implement multiple approvals (reviews) for syncing in ArgoCD

Tags: argocd

I thought that's an easy one, but could not find any resource yet describing it. On a production stage, there should be more than one person validating the out-of-sync diffs and hitting (reviewing and approving) the button for syncing for any registered application in ArgoCD. So, the resource should be only synced after two separate persons approved it.

How could this be implemented?

Comment: Use auto-sync and rather apply the approval in your Git tool with PR/MR (Gitlab/GitHub). ArgoCD is not a place to have approval workflows.